# Spark Structured Streaming Foreachbatch [ pyspark]

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

We are using spark Structured  Streaming  with foreachbatch to update records in delta table. The number of records part of each batch are random. We have 10000 record in kinesis stream but while creating  micro batch it picks random number of records that is some time 800, 500 and some time . This takes long time in processing because  ideally it should create 2 batch of 5000 each.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please post a code snippet?  You may find this Best Practices: Delta Lake Structured Streaming with Amazon Kinesis post useful: https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/kinesis-best-practices.html